# selenium python: how to send keys to a hidden password with differnet IDs

Tags: python, html, selenium, authentication, passwords

I'm currently using selenium with python 2.7 and I'm trying to to insert a password to the following form:

```
<tr id="mockpass">
    <td>
        <input type="text" value="something1" onfocus="document.getElementById('mockpass').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('realpass').style.display=''; document.getElementById('Irealpass').focus();">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="realpass" style="display: none;">
    <td>
        <input type="password" name="Password" id="Irealpass" onblur="if(this.value=='') {document.getElementById('mockpass').style.display='';
         document.getElementById('realpass').style.display='none';}">
       </td>
</tr>
```

I tried using the following code but I keeping getting an error while trying to excute the clear command:

```
        passBoxXpath='//*[@id="mockpass"]/td/input'
        passBoxElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(passBoxXpath))

        passBoxElement.click()
        passElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="Password"]'))
        passElement = driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'block'; return arguments[0];",
                                            passElement)

        passElement.clear()
        passElement.send_keys("myPassword")
```

The error:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
InvalidElementStateException: Message: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated
```

I'm not sure if it's something to do with the focus or the blur that changes the element, but I get the element and fail to accsses it.

Thanks in advance!

**update**: the next line solved my case (still don't know why it didn't work):

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("Irealpass").setAttribute("value","myPassword");')
```

In this way I didn't need to use the passBoxElement at all or changing the display style.

Comment: on which of provided lines you get exception?

Comment: on passElement.clear()

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io, this code should work.
`elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#mockpass input:first-child")`

If you get the error anyway, scroll the browser window to element you are trying to access.

Comment: It didn't work, it just like if I would try to send the password to passBoxElement (and I need to sent it passElement).

Answer (score 0):

A couple things...

First off, if you are trying to perform user scenarios, you want to avoid using `JavascriptExecutor` (JSE). JSE allows you to do things on a page that an actual user cannot. Avoid using JSE unless you absolutely have to or if you don't care about user scenarios.

The problem is that the `input` that you want is hidden in the HTML you provided. You can see that in the 2nd `TR`, `style="display: none;"`. If you look in the HTML of the first `INPUT`, you will see that the `onfocus` hides the first `TR`

```
onfocus="document.getElementById('mockpass').style.display='none';
```

and then unhides the 2nd `TR`

```
document.getElementById('realpass').style.display='';
```

So what you need to do is to focus the first `INPUT` which will expose the second `INPUT`.

One thing to note, from the JS in the second `INPUT` it looks like if you value is empty, it will rehide the second `INPUT` and expose the first (undoing what you just did).

```
onblur="if(this.value=='') {docum ...
```

I would do something like this

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mockpass"]/td/input')).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Irealpass"]')).send_keys("myPassword")
```

Answer (score 0):

Below should be work:

```
passwdEle = self.driver.find_element(by='id', value='Irealpass') 
self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].setAttribute("value","****")', passwdEle)
```